# Error when I upload .sol file to Azure Blockchain Workbench

Tags: azure, blockchain

When I try to upload .sol file to Azure Blockchain Workbench, an error occurs. What does it mean? My code is just copied from sample code provided from Microsoft at GitHub.

[image]

Comment: Can you please update the links as both leads to error image.

Comment: Could you share the sol and json files?